# Django: How can I create a multiple select form?

Tags: python, django, forms, field, multiple-select

I'm beginner in Django/Python and I need to create a multiple select form. I know it's easy but I can't find any example. I know how to create a CharField with a widget but I get confused of all the options inside [fields.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3/django/forms/fields.py).

For example I don't know which one of the followings is best for a multiple select form.

```
'ChoiceField', 'MultipleChoiceField',
'ComboField', 'MultiValueField',
'TypedChoiceField', 'TypedMultipleChoiceField'
```

And here is the form I need to create.

```
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <select name="countries" id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="AUT" selected="selected">Austria</option>
            <option value="DEU" selected="selected">Germany</option>
            <option value="NLD" selected="selected">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="USA">United States</option>
        </select>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;"></p>
    </form>
```

EDIT:

One more small question. If I want to add to each option one more attribute like *data*:

```
 <option value="AUT" selected="selected" data-index=1>Austria</option>
```

How can I do it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think [`CheckboxSelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) should work according to your problem.

In your `forms.py`, write the below code:

```
from django import forms


class CountryForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = (
        ("AUT", "Austria"),
        ("DEU", "Germany"),
        ("NLD", "Neitherlands"),
    )
    Countries = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                          choices=OPTIONS)
```

In your `views.py`, define the following function:

```
def countries_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CountryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            countries = form.cleaned_data.get('countries')
            # do something with your results
    else:
        form = CountryForm

    return render_to_response('render_country.html', {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In your `render_country.html`:

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes this is but one more thing small... If i want to add to each option a data property like this <option value="DEU" selected="selected" data-index=1>Germany</option> how i can do it? Also missing the last option which is not selected. Thanks anyway

Comment: Not sure!! make the form as model form. I believe then atleast in backend a primary key will be associated. Need to check it out.

Comment: and if my first answer satisfy your query , please consider accepting the answer . :)

Comment: Good answer @vibhor but "AUT" != "Australia" as stated in your code, it's Austria. Sorry to be a pedant, we Australians get that a lot and we're a bit sensitive about it :-)

Answer (score 6):

I did it in this way :

**forms.py**

```
class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['countries'] =  ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.all()),
                                             empty_label="Choose a countries",)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import * 
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',CreateView.as_view(model=YourModel, get_success_url=lambda: reverse('model_countries'),
        template_name='your_countries.html'), form_class=ChoiceForm, name='model_countries'),)
```

**your_countries.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It is works fine in my example, If you need something more, just ask me!!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to my second question this is the solution. An extending class:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from itertools import chain
from django.utils.html import escape, conditional_escape

class Select(forms.Select):
    """
    A subclass of Select that adds the possibility to define additional 
    properties on options.

    It works as Select, except that the ``choices`` parameter takes a list of
    3 elements tuples containing ``(value, label, attrs)``, where ``attrs``
    is a dict containing the additional attributes of the option.
    """
    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        def render_option(option_value, option_label, attrs):
            option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
            selected_html = (option_value in selected_choices) and u' selected="selected"' or ''
            attrs_html = []
            for k, v in attrs.items():
                attrs_html.append('%s="%s"' % (k, escape(v)))
            if attrs_html:
                attrs_html = " " + " ".join(attrs_html)
            else:
                attrs_html = ""
            return u'<option value="{0}"{1}{2}>{3}</option>'.format(
                escape(option_value), selected_html, attrs_html, 
                conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
                )
            '''
            return u'<option value="%s"%s%s>%s</option>' % (
                escape(option_value), selected_html, attrs_html,
                conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label)))
            '''
        # Normalize to strings.
        selected_choices = set([force_unicode(v) for v in selected_choices])
        output = []
        for option_value, option_label, option_attrs in chain(self.choices, choices):
            if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
                output.append(u'<optgroup label="%s">' % escape(force_unicode(option_value)))
                for option in option_label:
                    output.append(render_option(*option))
                output.append(u'</optgroup>')
            else:
                output.append(render_option(option_value, option_label,
                    option_attrs))
        return u'\n'.join(output)

class SelectMultiple(forms.SelectMultiple, Select):
    pass
```

Example:

```
OPTIONS = [
        ["AUT", "Australia", {'selected':'selected', 'data-index':'1'}],
        ["DEU", "Germany", {'selected':'selected'}],
        ["NLD", "Neitherlands", {'selected':'selected'}],
        ["USA", "United States", {}]
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know your problem has been solved but from my research on Django Multiple Checkbox I discovered that the best way or practice is to use django-multiselectfield package. You first need to install it using pip: `pip install django-multiselectfield` then add it to installed apps in settings.py; `'multiselectfield'`. Import the package in your models.py file: `from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField` then below is how you go about your models and form:
Models code:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
    ('Nigeria', 'Nigeria'),
    ('USA', 'USA'),
    ('UK', 'UK'),
    ('Ghana', 'Ghana'),
    )
    favourates = MultiSelectField(choices = COUNTRY_CHOICES)
```

form.py code:

```
class CountriesForm(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Country
```

views.py code:
Import the form in the views then do the following in function view for the template to display the checkboxes.

```
def UserCountryLikes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CountriesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            country.form = CountriesForm(commit=False)
            country.save()
    else:
        form = CountryForm()
    context = {
    'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'app_name_folder_template/form_template.html', context)
```

In the Template (form_template.html in the views.py) to display the form do the following:

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input class="btn btn-info mt-3" type="submit" value="Add Drinks">

    </form>
```

Remember to run migrations and migrate

Answer (score 1):

[ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) is your friend. A CharField is capable of storing one selection, but not multiple, without some extra work, which I would recommend against.

[API doc for ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield)

Answer (score 1):

You can also define countries field in your form class as

```
Countries = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
                                             choices=OPTIONS_TUPPLE)
```

I don't know which one is better in SelectMultiple and CheckboxSelectMultiple but it also works.

For more details you can use django documentation about [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/).

Answer (score 1):

Working with widget=forms **CheckboxSelectMultiple** is quite difficult when you want to select multiple values.
(Remember Multiple select is for ManytoMany key Field)

In this condition **SelectMultiple** is better as you can select multiple items with ctrl or select all items with ctrl+a.

```
class MyModalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = MyModel
        widgets = {            
            'products': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'required': True})
        }
```

if you wants dynamic values for multiple select you can do this with **init**

```
class MyModalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = MyModel
        widgets = {            
            'products': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'required': True})
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        selected_products = kwargs.pop('selected_products', None)   ##queryset returned from function
        self.fields['products'].queryset = selected_products
        self.fields['orders'].queryset = OrderModal.objects.filter(pk=2)
```