# I can't import multiselectfield

Tags: django, django-multiselectfield

I'm trying to use `multiselectfield` in Django although I installed it with `pip install django-multiselectfield` and put it in my `INSTALLED_APPS` but I can't import it in my forms.py file... what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

multiselectfield should be added on models.py. After creating the MultiSelectField on your model, you can loop it in your form ( See [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/) Docs)

Alternatively, CheckboxSelectMultiple might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15393771/12958385

Comment: it doesn't make any difference i can't import it ,my interpreter can't recognize it

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link. CheckboxSelectMultiple is widget in form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15393771/12958385